# Serialize/Deserialize Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] using Serialize.Linq

Tags: c#, json, linq, serialization

Coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633582/compile-expression-at-runtime-using-serialize-linq), I have almost the same need.

I want to serialize an array of predicates (`Expression<Func<T, bool>>[]`) to send it over a gRPC connection.

On the server side, I'm looping through each predicate from the array to apply a WHERE clause on an IQueryable :

```
foreach (var predicate in predicates)
{
    items = items.Where(predicate);
}
```

So my method's signature looks like that : `public Task<List<T>> Get(params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] predicates)`

Using the [Serialize.Linq](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq) library, I serialize my array of predicates like that :

```
var serializedPredicates =
    predicates
    .Select(x => _serializer.SerializeText(x));
var request = new GetRequest()
{
    Filters = JsonSerializer.Serialize(serializedPredicates)
};
```

So I use the library to create a list of string (serialized expressions), then I serialize this list using the usual `System.Text.Json` library to send it  over gRPC.

But I'm not able to deserialize this list on the server side.

Here is the code of the deserialization :

```
var serializedPredicates = 
    JsonSerializer
    .Deserialize<IEnumerable<string>>(request.Filters);

var predicates =
    serializedPredicates
    .Select(x => _serializer.DeserializeText(x))
    .ToArray();

var result = await service.Get(predicates);
```

So I take the `request.Filters` and deserialize it as a list of string, then for each string I deserialize it using the `Serialize.Linq` library (`_serializer.DeserializeText(x)`) and  apply `.ToArray()` to get an array of `Expression`.

Unfortunately, I can only get a `Expression[]` using this method (which is already kinda ugly), but I'm not having a true `Expression<Func<T, bool>>[]` like my method is awaiting.

So it obviously results in an error :

> Exception was thrown by handler. RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'Tests.Repository<DataModel.TestData>.Get(params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<DataModel.TestData,bool>>[])' has some invalid arguments

Because I'm using gRPC, I can't create a generic service. It would have been easier to cast the deserialization like that :`.Select(x => (Expression<Func<T, bool>>) _serializer.DeserializeText(x))` but I don't know the type of T before the running time.

I also tried using

```
var predicatesType = typeof(Expression<>)
    .MakeGenericType(Expression.GetFuncType(requestType, typeof(bool)));
...
.Select(x => Convert.ChangeType(_serializer.DeserializeText(x), predicatesType))
```

where the `requestType` is sent over gRPC too, to retrieves the Type in a variable. But unfortunately the `Expression` does not seem to be convertible :

> Exception was thrown by handler. InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible

How can I properly serialize a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>[]` and deserialize it as a proper `Expression<Func<T, bool>>[]` ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly I'm missing something obvious here, but assuming that you have all the required types on the client side (otherwise I doubt this should work at all) - have you tried just casting the expressions to the required type:

```cs
var predicates = serializedPredicates
    .Select(x => _serializer.DeserializeText(x))
    .Cast<Expression<Func<DataModel.TestData, bool>>>()
    .ToArray();
```

If needed - move the casting to helper method (or use [`Enumerable.Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-7.0) itself) and invoke it dynamically via reflection.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I don't know the type in advance on the server side, but I can't use T as I'm using gRPC which wait for a concrete Type. I'm getting this type using the typeof().MakeGenericType();

Comment: @M.Ozn extract this code into generic helper method and call it "dynamicly"

Comment: Ok I reworked my code to adapt it to your answer, everything works now ! Thanks